# Bijection between continuous maps $B\to S$ and open subsets of $B$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Is my solution of the following problem correct?

> Let $S$ be the two-point topological space in which exactly one of the singleton subsets is open. Prove that continuous maps from a space $B$ to $S$ correspond bijectively to open subsets of $B$.

Let $S=\{\star,\bullet\}$ and let $\{\bullet\}$ be the singleton subset that is open.

Define the map $F$ from cts maps $B\to S$ to open subsets of $B$ by sending  a cts map $\phi:B\to S$ to the subset $\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})$.  This is an open subset of $B$ because $\phi$ is continuous.

Define the map $G$ in the opposite direction by assigning to an open subset $U$ of $B$ the function $\psi_U:B\to S$ that sends every element of $U$ to $\bullet$ and every element outside of $U$ to $\star$. This map is continuous because the preimage of every open subset is open: the preimages of $\emptyset$ and $S$ are, respectively, $\emptyset$ and $B$ (which are open), and the preimage of $\{\bullet\}$ is the open subset $U$.

Let us check that $FG=1$ and $GF=1$.

1) $F(G(U))=F(\psi_U)=\psi_U^{-1}(\{\bullet\})=U$.

2) $G(F(\phi:B\to S))=G(\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\}))=\psi_{\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})}$. To see that $\phi=\psi_{\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})}$, note that $\psi_{\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})}$ sends to $\bullet$ those and only those elements $x$ for which $x\in \phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})$ (i.e., for which $\phi(x)\in\{\bullet\}$, i.e., for which $\phi(x)=\bullet$) -- that is, $\psi_{\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})}$ sends to $\bullet$ precisely the same elements that $\phi$ sends to $\bullet$, and $\psi_{\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})}$ sends the other elements to $\star$ (which holds for $\phi$ as well). Thus $\phi=\psi_{\phi^{-1}(\{\bullet\})}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and very precise!

As a point of improvement: you did not explicitly define $G$ anywhere. From the context I can see that you mean by $G$ the operation that assigns to an open $U$ the map $\psi_U$, but you never really define this.